# Devise how to access resource/resource_name in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using devise in my rails application and I have two different resource types, like users and companies.

I would like to reuse some code in views, so inspite of writing

```
if user_logged_in?
   current_user.name 
else  
   current_company.name
```

I would like to do this the way devise does:

```
resource.name
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What about writing an application helper with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "the way devise does", but you could make an application helper like apnea.diving.deep suggested. Just put this in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` (you might want to put it in a different file):

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def resource_name
    if user_logged_in?
      current_user.name
    else
      current_company.name
    end
  end
end
```

You can now use `resource_name` in your views.

(Also, just FYI, the short code snippet you wrote (`if user_logged_in?...` will fail, as "if"s needs to end with "end"s)